# Is modify goal state affect how to check 8puzzle solvability?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I know we can check the solvability of traditional 8puzzle by check how many inversion at initial state, but what if we modify the goal state we want, is this still work? or what should we do to make this work on a modify goal state?

traditional 8puzzle goal state:

```
{
  {1,2,3},
  {4,5,6},
  {7,8,0}
}
```

modified 8puzzle goal state:

```
{
  {1,2,3},
  {8,0,4},
  {7,6,5}
}
```

I did try to read the about the state's parity, bur I am still quite confuse.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to apply the normal inversion check against all possible permutations, you could neatly divide them into two sets-- solvable and unsolvable.  In both sets, every member can reach the state of every other member of the same set through some sequence of board moves.

If you're given a starting board and an ending board and want to know if one board can reach the other through some series of moves, you only need to show that both boards are members of the same set, that is, the solvable set or the unsolvable set.  The "parity" is a way of describing whether both board states belong to the same set or different set.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any goal state to the standard goal state by renaming the tiles. You can apply this renaming to you initial state and than use the traditional solvability check.